# UWP (Windows 10 APP) - appcert.exe crashes before my app get tested

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, uwp, app-certification-kit

I've developed an simple and small Universal Windows App that uses EF7 and SQLite. The app builds normally and it runs perfectly from Visual Studio. I also can run it directly from Windows 10 in the start menu after the I side loaded it (once the app package is generated).

My problem is that I can't test the app after it's package is generated because of an error on appcert.exe.

If I generate app package to x86 when launching windows app certification from visual studio right after the package is generated I get the error "***the appxbundle could not be implanted***" even before the test starts.

If I generate app package to x64 when launching windows app certification from visual studio right after the package is generated the test starts normally  but before it's done I get the following error: "***an unhandled microsoft .netframework exception occurred in appcertui.exe***".

The appcert.exe crashes and does not tell me why.

I've searched in google and I've looked at windows log event but found nothing helpful.

I just don't know what to do. My app is finished, I can generate it´s package but I can´t generate the ".appxupload" because of this error I mentioned.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you run appcertui.exe directly and get its first screen/menu? "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\appcertui.exe"  Please confirm version of VS, and that you have no pending updates on your machine.

Comment: When I open appcertui.exe I see the main screen but right after I click in "Validate store app" button I get the following error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Fail retrieving the COM class factory from the component with CLSID {3866CD68-0FC3-4563-8888-E107295BC485} because of the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

**And this is my Visual Studio information:**
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038

Comment: shot in the dark: repair visual studio, reboot after even if not prompted.

Comment: Already tried this. I've also reinstalled Windows 10 SDK but nothing changed.
My guess is the problem is not in Visual Studio but in the SDK or in the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 2):

The file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\binaryinfo.dll` is `CLSID {3866CD68-0FC3-4563-8888-E107295BC485}` on my machine.

I was able to reproduce your crash by unregistering binaryinfo.dll on my machine and clicking "Validate Store App".

Maybe a fix for your issue to do register this dll (maybe all of them?).

**From an administrator/elevated command prompt**

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\binaryinfo.dll"
```

How your machine got into this state...unknown.

Comment: My machine doesn't even have the file "binaryinfo.dll". All I could find is a file called **"microsoft.windows.softwarelogo.binaryinfo.interop.dll"** in that same path. I've searched the CLSID {3866CD68-0FC3-4563-8888-E107295BC485} in Windows register but found nothing usefull. It points to a utility class. Should I register all the dll files in the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\"?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a fresh install of Windows 10 and its SDK in a virtual machine on Virtual Box.  The appcertui.exe is running fine and my app was tested successfully.

It might be a problem in the installation of the .NET Framework since I updated from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

I will try to completely reinstall both .NET Framework and the SDK to solve this issue. If none of this works I will reinstall Windows 10 from scratch on my computer.